# Neo4j isochrones and Nosql isochrones

Tags: neo4j

I am currently researching on the Nosql's graph world, my task is to generate isochrones from a specified point A. To generate isochrones means that I want to find all paths starting from A and terminating on a node X within a certain total cost specified on the relations that connect nodes.
I'm currently trying this on Neo4j but every algorithm I have seen so far need a start-node A and an end-node B, that's is not exactly what I'm looking for because I do not know the nodes at the end of the paths, these nodes is what I need to discover.
Is there any chance to do that in Neo4j (or in another Nosql graph db) without writing my own algorithm?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but you might want to edit your question to show a sample graph. Also: This question will likely be closed as off-topic due to you asking for other graph database engines (which becomes a tool recommendation question).

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I do not think this is off-topic I'm talking about Neo4j and I can immagine that if someone had this problem in Neo4j he may only any other tool-recommendation-advices about THIS topic. 
Mattia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

1. Find the starting node
2. Find all paths from this node to other nodes
3. Calculate the minumum cost of the paths for terminating node
4. Aggregate nodes on the path cost

For example:

```
MATCH (S) WHERE ID(S) = {start_node_id} 
WITH S
MATCH path = (S)-[*]->(E) 
WITH E, 
     MIN( REDUCE(cost=0, r IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) | cost + r.weight) ) AS cost
RETURN cost, 
       collect(E) as isochrones 
ORDER BY cost
```

Comment: Thank you so much stdob-- it is without any doubt usefull. I'm managing with a VERY LARGE (immagine the OSM graph of Italy) dataset, if I apply this solution it will calculate every possibile path to every node. This is not obviously the best idea because it will surely crash, I need to limit the path calculated only to an appropriate range of nodes. How about to suppose a number of maximum relations and limit the (S)-[*]->(E) relation? For example (S)-[*20]->(E). I think that in this way it will not calculate every path to very distant nodes that is not usefull for me.

Comment: What may be restrictions on the paths? Can you show a graph structure?

Comment: Every node is a point on the italic ground made by: Lat,Long,ID.
Every relation is a street connecting two points on the ground made by: id start, id end, cost (minutes that a vehicle needs to go from start to end).
The db is made by milions of rows and deeply interconnected.
My query would be: "give me every point reachable within 60 minutes from a node X".
If I use your solution as it is written it will calculate every possible path on the graph from that node X, but I do not need to calculate paths that go over 60 minutes, I possibly have to prune it BEFORE they are computed.

Comment: @MattiaGallegati What minimum value of cost? And what type of cost values? Integer or Float?

Comment: Well it can be managed as I want, right now I have the cost expressed in seconds (float) and if I want to find all the nodes reacheable in 30 min I can simply express it in seconds doing 30*60, this can be Integer or Float by choice. The minimum value of cost can be like 0.5 seconds.